# select change color pattern wont show

Tags: javascript

```
function colorSelectCheck(){
        var select_val = $('#color_Pattern_selector').val();
    if(select_val)
    {
       colorPattern(select_val);
       //show the pattern i wanted
       //colorPattern(RedBox);
       alert(select_val);
    }

    return;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#color_Pattern_selector").change(colorSelectCheck).change();  
    });
```

my intention is changing the color pattern depends on select value , but the color wont add if i pass those array to select.

here is my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/qryhth6u/1/)

remove the // on colorPattern(RedBox) to show what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `color_Pattern_box` is a string containing the name of the varible you want to use, not the actual variable itself.

Add your color arrays to an object with their names as property names

```
var BoxColors = {
   "RedBox": ["#FFEBEE", "#E57373", "#F44336", "#B71C1C"],
   "PinkBox": ["#F48FB1", "#E91E63", "#AD1457"]
};
```

Then use the value of the select box as an object property name to select the correct color array

```
var colorArray = BoxColors[select_val];
colorPattern(colorArray);
```

Demo

```js
var BoxColors = {
  RedBox: ["#FFEBEE", "#E57373", "#F44336", "#B71C1C"],
  PinkBox: ["#F48FB1", "#E91E63", "#AD1457"]
};


function colorPattern(color_Pattern_box){
  var color_Board = $('#colorBoard');
  var color_temp = ('');

  for(var c = 0; c < color_Pattern_box.length; c++){
    color_temp += "<li class='mycolor'; id="+color_Pattern_box[c]+" style='background: "+color_Pattern_box[c]+";'></li>";

  }
  color_Board.html(color_temp);   
}


function colorSelectCheck(){
  var select_val = $('#color_Pattern_selector').val();

  if(select_val) {
    colorPattern(BoxColors[select_val]);
  }

  return;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#color_Pattern_selector").change(colorSelectCheck).change();  
});
```

```css
.mycolor{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="color_Pattern_selector">
    <option value="RedBox">Red</option>
    <option value="PinkBox">Pink</option>
</select>

<ul id="colorBoard"></ul>
```

Comment: thank clear explanation and well fix , thank you is all i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That's a refference problem, but if you use eval you can do it. Take carefully with `eval()`, don't use it without ask your parents first ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/qryhth6u/2/

```
colorPattern(eval(select_val));
```